# (Edited) What is the noun for ''the way of thinking about what could have happened in the past all the time''

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

in short the noun defines 'thinking and talking about what ifs a lot'

Edit: Unfortunately none of the answers came with the word i'm looking for and I'm sorry I was not fully prepared when I first asked the question.

Context:

Counterfactual history uses hypothetical thought-experiments to imagine the probable results of changes in the historical record. The hypotheses are two-part conditional statements, consisting of an ‘if’ and a ‘then’ clause: if the Luftwaffe had won the air battle, then the Germans might have successfully invaded Britain. Military historians have used counterfactual analysis for centuries. Among professional historians, they are still the most consistent practitioners.

So now the question is 'what could we call those particular military historians?'
Bear in mind that they do the counterfactual analysis excessively.

Comment: Do you have any research?

Comment: Probably *most* people who are obsessed with hypothetical "What If" scenarios are primarily focused on possible ***futures*** (where we don't *know* what will actually happen). But (at least in principle) for ***past*** situations we *do* know what did or didn't happen. So are you talking about people who think a lot about what might have happened (but in fact *didn't*), or what perhaps *really* happened (but maybe we can't be sure). And do these people think those possible past situations were / would have been ***good**?* Or are they glad they *didn't* happen ('cos they'd be ***bad***?).

Comment: @FumbleFingers it's for the situations that actually didn't happen in the past and i'm not sure about your second question but i reckon it's the former, maybe they tend to fantasize about what might have happened instead of what really happened.

Comment: Please refer to the section on [How do I ask a good question?](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  We need some context in order to understand & answer your Q. properly.  Meanwhile your question has been automatically "flagged as low-quality because of its length and content."

Answer (score 1):

As for the 'thinking about what could have happened in the past all the time' part, I think *retrospection* fits quite nicely:

> **retrospection**
>
> NOUN
>
> the act of thinking now about something in the past
>
> Examples:
>
> *He is a man of action, not retrospection.*

([Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/retrospection))

However, I think *speculation* captures 'thinking and talking about what ifs a lot' better:

> **speculation**
>
> NOUN
>
> ideas or guesses about something that is not known

([Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/speculation))

*Speculation* might refer to the past, the present, or the future, though. If you meant 'the act of living in the past', then *retrospection* is a better choice, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be one of the following forms 
from https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/woulda,_coulda,_shoulda:

shoulda, coulda, woulda

shoulda, woulda, coulda

woulda, shoulda, coulda

coulda, shoulda, woulda

coulda, woulda, shoulda

woulda, coulda, shoulda

"An expression of dismissiveness or disappointment concerning a statement, question, explanation, course of action, or occurrence involving hypothetical possibilities, 
uncertain facts, or missed opportunities.

(This stems from expressing that someone could have, would have and/or should have done something)."